# How to fix ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE on a single network

Tags: router, dns, dns-cache

I'm a huge fan of Anime and I do read up a lot about the stories in the wikia site. However, since the last week, it wasn't accessible to me, that too only under my home WiFi.

- The URL of the site is http://naruto.wikia.com/
- It do not open up stating ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHEABLE error in Chrome.

Things I tried:

- Run it against isup.me site. It's definitely up.
- Try opening it in other devices (my main desktop, secondary laptop and 4 mobile phones). None works.
- Stop connecting to my home WiFi and connect to mobile data hotspot instead. Works blazingly fast.
- Thought of it as some caching, so I tried changing the DNS servers from ISP ones to Google's, OpenDNS, and also the latest CloudFlare 1.1.1.1 DNS. None works.
- Flush the DNS cache in my systems using NSCD (I run Ubuntu on all my systems). Did no effect.
- Deleted the WiFi configuration, rebooted a few times and reconnect. No luck either.
- Load it from a VPN, it works suddenly. I've checked with ISP and got clarified that the site is not banned in my country.
- Tried resetting the router, but got no luck there either.

Some specs:

My OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Router: DLINK DIR-300
Laptop: Lenovo E41

P.S.: Ping doesn't connect either, it just says 100% packet loss.

Is there anything else I could try before contacting the ISP support team? Please guide me how to solve it.

Comment: I assume you cannot connect to wikia.com?  You changed the DNS servers of your access point not the client you were using I presume?

Comment: @Ramhound I just tried that as well. Unfortunately nope. I even rebooted both the system and the router.

Comment: If you connect to a proxy or VPN on the client, are you able to, access the website?  You can use TOR to accomplish this if you have no other options.

Comment: Well, that is an option I want to avoid. All the systems I had are provided to me by the company I work at (I live in their quarters) so I can't install new software without prior approval.

Comment: If you are unable to use a proxy or VPN then you cannot rule out the fact, your companies firewall is blocking or filtering the content

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't the case either, as the WiFi was bought by me, from a third-party other than the one provided by my company.

Comment: You made no mention of that fact in your question body.  The use of a vpn or proxy is the only way to determine if the content is being filtered.